# Trying to read from a text file to display into a JTextArea using a BufferedReader

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader, jtextarea

So I am trying to read a text file to display into a JTextArea I am having no luck getting it to show up. I believe the problem lies around the setup of my BufferedReader but I am not certain. It also may be a problem with my SOP section. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WindowInventory extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea ta_inventory;

    public WindowInventory() {
        setSize(200, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Inventory");
        setLocation(200, 200);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        ta_inventory = new JTextArea();
        ta_inventory.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 350);
        contentPane.add(ta_inventory);

        try {

            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Inventory.txt"));

            while (myReader.ready()) {

                String Name = myReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(Name);
                String Price = myReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(Price);
                String ID = myReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(ID);

            }

            myReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Problem reading from a file");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [`JTextArea#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object)) instead

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your method of setting up the reader is wrong.  Take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) for more deatils.

However, you could try using something more like...

```
try (BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Inventory.txt"))) {
    String text = null;
    while ((text = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead.

Now having said that.  It would be easier to simple use [`JTextArea#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object))

Something like....

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
try (Reader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Inventory.txt"))) {
    textArea.read(myReader, "Inventory");
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Text components like `JTextArea` really should be maintained within a `JScrollPane`.  See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing, `textArea.read(new BufferedReader(myReader), "Inventory");`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Possibly, but know you have a reader which is still hanging around (sure the underlying reader will be closed, but still)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It did some (simple) performance testing some time ago and found generally (at least over small files) there wasn't that much difference between a reader and a buffered reader on the local disk.  Not saying that you should throw buffered reader away though...

Comment: Well of course the BufferedReader could be part of the try block resources.

Comment: I don't know if it will actually buffer the input or not, which is why I asked this. Thanks for your thoughts, and sorry for hijacking this question. 1+